# Engenharia reversa não atualizar novos objetos Oracle Data Modeler

Tags: oracle

estou com um problema com o Data Modeler.
Etou usando o Oracle Data Modeler. Eu fiz engenharia reversa para gerar modelo físico.
Quando eu fiz as modificações na base de dados e quis atualizar o modelo. Não veio os novos objetos, apenas a atualzação nos objetos antigos.
Como soluciono este problema?. Obrigado

estou usando:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
SQL Developer:  Versão 4.0.0.13 Build MAIN-13.80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive o mesmo problema, até que resolvi importar o modelo novamente e o mesmo me deu a opção de Mesclar Modelo Atualizado com os novos campos e *constraints* que criei.

Comment: Exato, no caso o Data Modeler só sincroniza os objetos já importados. Caso exista um objeto novo, ele tem que ser importado.

Comment: vide comentário do @thatjeffsmith http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511839/reverse-engineer-not-update-new-objetcs-oracle-data-modeler